# MVC, ListBoxFor makes EditorFor empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I've just started my journey with MVC, but I have a problem and for two days I can't find answer. 
I have EditorFor and ListBoxFor in a one site and I want to Post info from EditorFor about Name and from ListBoxFor about EmployeeId.

In listbox I have list of my employees. I can write name in Editor and I can choose one of employee from list.

Everything is ok, but when I mark anything inside ListBox it makes that text inside EditorFor disappears.

View:

```
@model Models.CreateClient

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div>
    <h4>Client</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Client.Name, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.Name, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedEmployee, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedtEmployee, Model.EmployeeListItem(), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedEmployee, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" value="CreateNew" class="btn btn-default " />
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
</div>
}
```

Model:

```
public class CreateClient
{
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedtEmployee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EmployeeListItem()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> employeeSelectedListItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var employee in Employees)
        {
            SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = employee.FullName,
                Value = employee.Id.ToString(),
            };
            employeeSelectedListItem.Add(selectListItem);
        }
        return employeeSelectedListItem;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult CreateNew()
    {
        CreateClient createClient = new CreateClient();
        createClient.Employees = db.EmployeeContet.ToList();

        return View(createClient);
    }
```

Comment: Not possible based on the code you have shown. But `ListBoxFor()` is for selecting multiple options (and property `SelectedtEmployee` needs to be `IEnumerable`) but your question suggest you only want to select one employee. And the fact you have  an associated `LabelFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor() which are for property `Client.EmployeeId` (not `SelectedtEmployee`) makes no sense either

Comment: I can only assume you mean that you enter a name, and when you submit  the form, you return the view and the text you entered is no longer displayed. You need to show you model and the controller code for this view.

Comment: You need to show the POST method as well (and as a side note, delete `Selected = employee.IsEmployeeSelected`- that does absolutely nothing - its the value of the property your binding to which determines what is selected. And having a class `Employee` that has a property `IsEmployeeSelected` makes no sense)

Comment: @StephenMuecke this happens before submit, my POST is empty. It happens just when I click Employee in ListBox. I removed IsEmployeeSelected, it was obsolete

Comment: Are you saying that you enter some text in the `Client.Name` textbox and then when you click on an option in the listbox that the name disappears? That is impossible unless you have some javascript on the page doing that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks! I opend it not in IE but in Chrome and Eureka! I made mistake and my Client's name was int (instead of string). Chrome showed me this.

Answer (score -1):

I made mistake and my Client's name was int (instead of string).

Comment: That does not explain the issue you described. And since this is of no use to anyone else, I suggest you just delete the answer and the question